# htaccess: simulating a switch-case on urls especially 'default'

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a site where I have to rewrite urls with htaccess. Is there a way to handle this like a switch's case statements?

Say my site is foobar.com, and I want

> foobar.com/red => foobar.com/republican.php
>
> foobar.com/blue => foobar.com/democrat.php
>
> foobar.com/green/xyz => foobar.com/green.php?id=xyz

default:

> foobar.com/* => foobar.com/page.php?query=*

Currently, this is my setup:

```
RewriteRule ^/red foobar.com/republican.php [works fine]

RewriteRule ^/blue foobar.com/democrat.php [works ok]

RewriteRule ^green/([^/.]+)/?$ green.php?id=$1
[error: redirect loop with foobar.com/green/home.php in browser address because green.php without id set redirects to home.php]

default [no idea how to implement]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way of doing this:

See 'using a route file' on http://kehers.github.io/2014/07/07/url-rewrites-with-apache-and-php.html